# C# async callback still on background thread...help! (preferably without InvokeRequired)

Tags: c#, events, generics, delegates, asynchronous

I am writing a very simple asynchronous helper class to go along with my project.  The purpose of the class is that it allows a method to be run on a background thread.  Here is the code;

```
    internal class AsyncHelper
    {
        private readonly Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        internal event DownloadCompleteHandler OnOperationComplete;

        internal void Start(Func func, T arg)
        {
            timer.Start();
            func.BeginInvoke(Done, func);
        }

        private void Done(IAsyncResult cookie)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            var target = (Func) cookie.AsyncState;
            InvokeCompleteEventArgs(target.EndInvoke(cookie));
        }

        private void InvokeCompleteEventArgs(T result)
        {
            var args = new EventArgs(result, null, AsyncMethod.GetEventByClass, timer.Elapsed);
            if (OnOperationComplete != null) OnOperationComplete(null, args);
        }

        #region Nested type: DownloadCompleteHandler

        internal delegate void DownloadCompleteHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

        #endregion
    }
```

The result of the task is then returned through the `OnOperationComplete` event.  The problem is that when the event is raised, its still on the background thread.  I.e. if I try to run this code (below) I get a cross threading error;

```
txtOutput.AppendText(e.Result + Environment.NewLine);
```

Please advise any thoughts.

Comment: Are you on .NET 2.0, 3.5, 4.0? And are you creating a WinForms, WPF, Silverlight application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use BackgroundWorker class. It essentially does the same you want.

```
        private BackgroundWorker _worker;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
        _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Work_Completed;
    }

    private void Work_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtOutput.Text = e.Result.ToString();
    }

    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Result = "Text received from long runing operation";
    }
```

Comment: You can also report progress setting:
_worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
//AND
_worker.ProgressChanged += Progress_Changed;

Comment: I kinda forgot... to actually run the worker you have to call the _worker.RunWorkerAsync() method.

Comment: i went for the BackgroundWorker in the end, but tucked it all away and put in custom events so that nobody will ever know.  Assuming they dont look at the source of course.  (The fact that the project is open source is a slight flaw, but oh well)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the `Task` class rather than `BackgroundWorker`, but [either would be greatly superior to `Control.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.Invoke`.](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html)

Example:

```
internal class AsyncHelper<T>
{ 
  private readonly Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch(); 
  private readonly TaskScheduler ui;

  // This should be called from a UI thread.
  internal AsyncHelper()
  {
    this.ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
  }

  internal event DownloadCompleteHandler OnOperationComplete; 

  internal Task Start(Func<T> func)
  { 
    timer.Start();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(func).ContinueWith(this.Done, this.ui);
  }

  private void Done(Task<T> task) 
  {
    timer.Stop();
    if (task.Exception != null)
    {
      // handle error condition
    }
    else
    {
      InvokeCompleteEventArgs(task.Result); 
    }
  } 

  private void InvokeCompleteEventArgs(T result) 
  { 
    var args = new EventArgs(result, null, AsyncMethod.GetEventByClass, timer.Elapsed); 
    if (OnOperationComplete != null) OnOperationComplete(null, args); 
  } 

  internal delegate void DownloadCompleteHandler(object sender, EventArgs e); 
}
```

This is very similar to a `BackgroundWorker`, though (except you're adding a timer). You may want to consider just using `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Did you read it? My "three pages" include a complete solution with user interface, support for cancellation, proper error marshalling, etc. None of which your solution includes.

Comment: I like this but not sure how to implement, could you give usage example?

Comment: I've updated the example to be similar to the code in your question, showing how it would be used in that situation.

Comment: hmm it still throws error;

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtOutput' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Did you construct `AsyncHelper` on the UI thread, as the comment indicated?

Comment: sorry i must have missed that.  the helper class originates from another class which is instantiated from the UI thread.  does that count.

Comment: Yes, as long as the UI thread has already created (and shown) a control.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke your event on the UI thread,

WinForms

`Form1.BeginInvoke(...);`

WPF

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);`

Comment: Are you suggesting this?;

<code>OnOperationComplete.BeginInvoke</code>

Comment: `ISynchronizeInvoke` is an outdated interface and should not be used.

Comment: @Jon, no, he's suggesting you call the BeginInvoke or Invoke method found on a visual control. That way you'll marshal the call over to the GUI thread, and that will allow you to manipulate the GUI state. `Delegate.BeginInvoke` and `Control.BeginInvoke` is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the BackgroundWorker class, you're basically reimplementing it here.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you build your help class to do the context switch internally you will always need to invoke in the event handler because in your code above you are raising the event on the non-ui thread.

To do that your helper needs to know how to get back on the ui thread. You could pass a [ISynchronizeInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.aspx) to the helper and then use it when done. Somwthing like:

```
ISynchronizeInvoke _sync;
internal void Start(Func func, T arg, ISynchronizeInvoke sync)
{
  timer.Start();
  func.BeginInvoke(Done, func);
  _sync = sync;
}

private void InvokeCompleteEventArgs(T result)
{
  var args = new EventArgs(result, null, AsyncMethod.GetEventByClass, timer.Elapsed);
  if (OnOperationComplete != null) 
     _sync.Invoke(OnOperationComplete, new object[]{null, args});
}
```

The `Control` class implements `ISynchronizeInvoke` so you can pass the `this` pointer from the `Form` or `Control` that calls the helper and has the event handler delegate,

Comment: `ISynchronizeInvoke` is an outdated interface and should not be used.